# ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined when using xadesjs

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using [xadesjs](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xadesjs) to sign my XMLs but I am getting following error

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at C:\Users\HP\WebstormProjects\nodeTest\node_modules\pkijs\build\CertificateChainValidationEngine.js:78:47
    at C:\Users\HP\WebstormProjects\nodeTest\node_modules\pkijs\build\CertificateChainValidationEngine.js:393:4
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\WebstormProjects\nodeTest\node_modules\pkijs\build\CertificateChainValidationEngine.js:2732:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I googled this error and found that this error is coming because of `babel` being used by this package or its dependencies.

My question is, can I do anything about this `babel` error, given that I am not a direct user of `babel`?

My code (its taken from their readme):

```
var xadesjs = require("xadesjs");
var WebCrypto = require("node-webcrypto-ossl");

xadesjs.Application.setEngine("OpenSSL", new WebCrypto());

// Generate RSA key pair
var privateKey, publicKey;
xadesjs.Application.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 1024, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: { name: "SHA-1" }, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
    },
    false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    ["sign", "verify"] //can be any combination of "sign" and "verify"
)
    .then(function (keyPair) {
        // Push ganerated keys to global variable
        privateKey = keyPair.privateKey;
        publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;

        // Call sign function
        var xmlString = '<player bats="left" id="10012" throws="right">\n\t<!-- Here\'s a comment -->\n\t<name>Alfonso Soriano</name>\n\t<position>2B</position>\n\t<team>New York Yankees</team>\n</player>';
        return SignXml(xmlString, keyPair, { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: { name: "SHA-1" } });
    })
    .then(function (signedDocument) {
        console.log("Signed document:\n\n", signedDocument);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });


function SignXml(xmlString, keys, algorithm) {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            var xmlDoc = xadesjs.Parse(xmlString);
            var signedXml = new xadesjs.SignedXml();

            return signedXml.Sign(               // Signing document
                algorithm,                              // algorithm
                keys.privateKey,                        // key
                xmlDoc,                                 // document
                {                                       // options
                    keyValue: keys.publicKey,
                    references: [
                        { hash: "SHA-256", transforms: ["enveloped"] }
                    ],
                    productionPlace: {
                        country: "Country",
                        state: "State",
                        city: "City",
                        code: "Code",
                    },
                    signingCertificate: "MIIGgTCCBGmgAwIBAgIUeaHFHm5f58zYv20JfspVJ3hossYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAk5MMSAwHgYDVQQKExdRdW9WYWRpcyBUcnVzdGxpbmsgQi5WLjEoMCYGA1UECxMfSXNzdWluZyBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTE3MDUGA1UEAxMuUXVvVmFkaXMgRVUgSXNzdWluZyBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eSBHMjAeFw0xMzEwMzAxMjI3MTFaFw0xNjEwMzAxMjI3MTFaMHoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdCcnVzc2VsMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlFdHRlcmJlZWsxHDAaBgNVBAoTE0V1cm9wZWFuIENvbW1pc3Npb24xFDASBgNVBAsTC0luZm9ybWF0aWNzMREwDwYDVQQDDAhFQ19ESUdJVDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJgkkqvJmZaknQC7c6H6LEr3dGtQ5IfOB3HAZZxOZbb8tdM1KMTO3sAifJC5HNFeIWd0727uZj+V5kBrUv36zEs+VxiN1yJBmcJznX4J2TCyPfLk2NRELGu65VwrK2Whp8cLLANc+6pQn/5wKh23ehZm21mLXcicZ8whksUGb/h8p6NDe1cElD6veNc9CwwK2QT0G0mQiEYchqjJkqyY8HEak8t+CbIC4Rrhyxh3HI1fCK0WKS9JjbPQFbvGmfpBZuLPYZYzP4UXIqfBVYctyodcSAnSfmy6tySMqpVSRhjRn4KP0EfHlq7Ec+H3nwuqxd0M4vTJlZm+XwYJBzEFzFsCAwEAAaOCAeQwggHgMFgGA1UdIARRME8wCAYGBACLMAECMEMGCisGAQQBvlgBgxAwNTAzBggrBgEFBQcCARYnaHR0cDovL3d3dy5xdW92YWRpc2dsb2JhbC5ubC9kb2N1bWVudGVuMCQGCCsGAQUFBwEDBBgwFjAKBggrBgEFBQcLAjAIBgYEAI5GAQEwdAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEaDBmMCoGCCsGAQUFBzABhh5odHRwOi8vb2NzcC5xdW92YWRpc2dsb2JhbC5jb20wOAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGLGh0dHA6Ly90cnVzdC5xdW92YWRpc2dsb2JhbC5jb20vcXZldWNhZzIuY3J0MEYGCiqGSIb3LwEBCQEEODA2AgEBhjFodHRwOi8vdHNhMDEucXVvdmFkaXNnbG9iYWwuY29tL1RTUy9IdHRwVHNwU2VydmVyMBMGCiqGSIb3LwEBCQIEBTADAgEBMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIGQDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTg+A751LXyf0kjtsN5x6M1H4Z6iDA7BgNVHR8ENDAyMDCgLqAshipodHRwOi8vY3JsLnF1b3ZhZGlzZ2xvYmFsLmNvbS9xdmV1Y2FnMi5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFDc3hgIFJTDamDEeQczI7Lot4uaVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4ICAQAZ8EZ48RgPimWY6s4LjZf0M2MfVJmNh06Jzmf6fzwYtDtQLKzIDk8ZtosqYpNNBoZIFICMZguGRAP3kuxWvwANmrb5HqyCzXThZVPJTmKEzZNhsDtKu1almYBszqX1UV7IgZp+jBZ7FyXzXrXyF1tzXQxHGobDV3AEE8vdzEZtwDGpZJPnEPCBzifdY+lrrL2rDBjbv0VeildgOP1SIlL7dh1O9f0T6T4ioS6uSdMt6b/OWjqHadsSpKry0A6pqfOqJWAhDiueqgVB7vus6o6sSmfG4SW9EWW+BEZ510HjlQU/JL3PPmf+Xs8s00sm77LJ/T/1hMUuGp6TtDsJe+pPBpCYvpm6xu9GL20CsArFWUeQ2MSnE1jsrb00UniCKslcM63pU7I0VcnWMJQSNY28OmnFESPK6s6zqoN0ZMLhwCVnahi6pouBwTb10M9/Anla9xOT42qxiLr14S2lHy18aLiBSQ4zJKNLqKvIrkjewSfW+00VLBYbPTmtrHpZUWiCGiRS2SviuEmPVbdWvsBUaq7OMLIfBD4nin1FlmYnaG9TVmWkwVYDsFmQepwPDqjPs4efAxzkgUFHWn0gQFbqxRocKrCsOvCDHOHORA97UWcThmgvr0Jl7ipvP4Px//tRp08blfy4GMzYls5WF8f6JaMrNGmpfPasd9NbpBNp7A=="
                })
            })
            .then(signature => signature.toString());
}
```

Comment: Try to use `babel-polyfill`. https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/issues/152

Comment: Add `require("babel-polyfill")` to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@microshine is right. PKIjs requires babel to be used in ES5 environment. This package takes PKIjs as dependency.